# Promise all race conditions with knex migrations

Tags: javascript, node.js, race-condition, knex.js

I've been told that there's no guarantee in the order in which a Promise.all resolves its promises. I don't, however, see that it doesn't resolve in order from the [Promise.all native docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Therefore, the following approach to knex migrations shouldn't work as `messages` has a reference to users table.

Yet, I've never run into an instance once, out of several migrations, where there's been an error with a race condition. Meaning, it seems like Promise.all resolves according to index position.

So, my question is: is the following snippet prone to a race condition?

```
    return Promise.all([
      knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
        table.increments().primary();
        ...
      }),
      knex.schema.createTable('messages', function(table) {
        table.increments().primary();
        table.bigInteger('user_id').unsigned().index()
          .references('id').inTable('users');
      }),
```

And is this the better approach?

```
    return Promise.all([
      knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
        table.increments().primary();
        ...
      }),
    ]).then(function() {
      return Promise.all([
         knex.schema.createTable('messages', function(table) {
           table.increments().primary();
           table.bigInteger('user_id').unsigned().index()
             .references('id').inTable('users');
         }),
       });
   })
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Promise.all` in your second snippet.

Comment: Assuming these are XHR calls, they will be initiated as soon as you exit the function scope. This means that the XHR requests will run concurrently. It could be that you're getting lucky and the order of the requests is completing just the way you want them to, but if `createTable('users')` needs to execute before `createTable('messages')`, then you should use a `.then()`: `knex.schema.createTable('users', ...).then(() => { knex.schema.createTable('messages') });`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a dependency, in that you need the first table to have been created before you can reference it in the second table, you should use the `then`-way.

Whether or not `Promise.all` will see its promises resolve in index order or not, has nothing to do with `Promise.all` itself, but with the individual promises passed to it as arguments. While you can expect JavaScript (not `Promise.all`) to evaluate the argument list in order, you cannot know in general which of those promises will resolve first. This is determined by those individual promises, not by `Promise.all`.

As in your case these individual promises do a similar thing, i.e. create a table, and your database engine will probably process those statements in order, without concurrency, you might in practice see that the promises always resolve in the order you listed them, but it would be bad practice to rely on that.

Note that if you pass an array with just one promise in it to `Promise.all` you can just skip that `Promise.all` and apply the `then` immediately to that single promise.

Comment: I've only listed one of my many promises in there for sake of brevity. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting that this code is in migration file, which  creates implicit transaction by default. So because queries are sent to the same connection they won't be resolved in parallel.

In this case database driver (at least `pg`) actually buffers the second query and waits until first query is resolved, before sending the second one to the db server.

Only thing that matters is that in which order those 2 queries are executed and sent to the pg-driver.

Since `Promise.all` doesn't guarantee that it will execute `knex.schema.createTable('users',...)` query before the `knex.schema.createTable('messages',...)` it means that there is theoretical possibility that first code will fail.

---

**tl;dr** first approach is not prone to race condition, but it may fail if the queries are executed in wrong order. The second approach is better.